# how to show out of stock on product image if the salable quantity is 0 in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

I want to show out of stock tag on products image if their salable quantity is 0 in Magento 2.3

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: call custom lable with out of stock product and you can use css to do the same

Answer (score 3):

How to Display Out of Stock Products in Magento 2.

> Go to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options

.

**Display Out of Stock Products:** Choose **Yes** to enable displaying out of stock products in the front end.

To enable the stock alert function of Magento 2, you need to allow this config to first.

After clean and refresh caching. may solve your issue .

Happy coding.

Comment: thanks issue resolved

Comment: hello, @Shahid Ali khan accept my question because of someone's help.